# Force an array to be an array of array

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, I would like to declare array of array.

Basically, if I write this code:

```
$array1 = ("AA", "BB")

$array2 = ("CC", "DD"),("EE", "FF")

$array1[0][0] + $array1[0][1]
$array2[0][0] + $array2[0][1]
$array2[1][0] + $array2[1][1]
```

I expect to get :

```
AABB
CCDD
EEFF
```

But the actual output is

```
AA
CCDD
EEFF
```

This is due because of the first array is detected as a simple string array, and not an array of array of string.

Is there any way to "force" `$array1` to be an array of one array ?

I tried:

```
$array1 = [string[][]]("AA", "BB")

$array1 = (("AA", "BB"))

$array1 = @()
$array1+=(@("AA","BB"))

$array1 = [array]::CreateInstance([array],1)
$array1[0] = @("AA","BB")
$array1[0][0] + $array1[0][1]
```

but none of these works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
$array1 = ,("AA", "BB")
```

the comma is the 'array operator' in powershell.